# How to calculate distance while running on Android?

Tags: android, gps, accelerometer

I understand that there are three approaches for it

1. **GPS Based:** Add up short distances travelled (calculated using Location.distanceTo) in small time intervals (5-10 secs), but this method is prone to GPS errors and would not work indoors or in short running area (like a small park)
2. **Double Integration of acceleration:** I can do double integral of accelerometer data to calculate distance but errors due to noise in accelerometer readings may add up.
3. **Step counting:** I can detect steps by measuring spikes in accelerometer data OR using Google Fit API and then multiply the total number of steps with the average stride length. But the problem here is figuring out average stride length.

I am inclined towards using #3 as it works indoors and is not much error prone OR battery draining. But How do I get average stride length for each step, especially when runner's stride varies in length when sprinting and jogging.

Does anyone know of any combination of these methods to get the best results? OR any other totally different but efficient method?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's engineering - there is no simple answer ;)
All these methods you've mentioned has their pros and cons.

GPS tracking won't sumarize errors of each measurement - it's great but on the other hand each location will be given with noticeable error. What is more you'll have problems with using your app in buildings etc.
Double integration of acceleration works great on small distances by the time error  grow to big number. It is also difficult to create program which will calculate it in appropriate way. There is a lot of important issues like e.g time of sampling or rotation and translation matrix calculation that makes these application very problematic on android.

In my app I used following algorytm:

1. Calculate location from GPS (from Network provider or GPS provider - best precision wins)
2. Start using accelerometer-based algorytm.
3. Stop using accelerometer-based algorytm when:

   - GPS and accelerometer measurements are very different
   - Accelerometer-based algorythm finds that calculated quaternions are different from what magnetometer says.
   - The velocity or acceleration from measurments is bigger than given value.
4. Go to point 1

Hope it helps

Comment: I get that the solution is not straightforward. What is your accelerometer based algorithm? and what is the "given value" of velocity in your thrid step?